# In Haskell Shake, how can I want a file pattern?

Tags: haskell, shake

I have a directory of xml files in a source directory that I want to turn into a directory of html files in a destination directory. It seems I can use `getDirectoryFiles` to get files from a directory, but that is an Action, and `want` needs not an `Action [FilePath]` but just a `[FilePath]`. How can I do something like `want ["dest/*.html"]` in Shake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do like this.

First of all, write a rule that creates the *html* file from *xml*.

```
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
    "dest/*.html" %> \out -> do
        let src = "source" </> dropDirectory1 out -<.> "xml"
        -- todo: generate out (HTML) from src (XML)
```

Then you can write a rule by `action` that will be run in every build execution.

```
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
    action $ do
        srcs <- getDirectoryFiles "source" ["*.xml"]
        need ["dest" </> src -<.> "html" | src <- srcs]

    "dest/*.html" %> \out -> do
        let src = "source" </> dropDirectory1 out -<.> "xml"
        -- todo: translate HTML(out) from XML(src)
```

---

For your information, `want` defined like: `want xs = action $ need xs`.

Answer (score 1):

`getDirectoryFiles` returns a result in the `Action` monad, but `want` returns a result in the `Rules` monad. You probably meant `need` instead, which is basically the same as `want` but in `Action`. Then just use `>>=` or `do` blocks like you would with any other monad:

```
do
  directoryFiles <- getDirectoryFiles path patterns
  need directoryFiles
```

If you want to end up back in `Rules` after that, then wrap the entire `do` block in a call to `action`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think `want` and `need` are interchangeable. `want` seems to: "Require that the argument files are built by the rules, used to specify the target." whereas `need` declares that target's dependencies. Could you change your answer to a minimum working example to show how a directory of an arbitrary number of files could be transformed into another directory of that same number of files?

Comment: `action` is how you move from `Action` to `Rules`, and `want` is basically just `action . need`.